# Tap Gesture on animating UIView not working

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a tap gesture on a UILabel who's translation is being animated. Whenever you tap on the label during the animation there's no response from the tap gesture.

Here's my code:

```
    label.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

    label.userInteractionEnabled = true
    label.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(12, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction, animations: { () -> Void in
        label.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 900)
        }, completion: nil)
```

Gesture code:

```
func setUpRecognizers() {
    tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "onTap:")
}
func onTap(sender : AnyObject) {
    print("Tapped")
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks :)

---

## Note added for 2021:

These days this is dead easy, you just override hitTest.

Comment: Maybe this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26210318/tap-gesture-with-uigesturerecognizerstate-not-working

Comment: Show your tap gesture initialization code.

Comment: for anyone googling here, take care, **the answer with a tick DOES NOT WORK and these days will crash you**.  it is now very easy to do this (I put in an answer showing how).  unfortunately this is an example on SO of an answer that is very out of date.  because the original question writer has disappeared, nobody can un-tick the ticked answer.

Comment: @Fattie thank you so much! This helped me immensely after hours of frustration. I wonder why this isnt solved by Apple.

Comment: @NiyogRay - right, it is one of those frustrating things about Apple.  And there's a real problem on SO .. the "ticked" answer here is **nowadays completely, totally wrong** .. but the problem is the user who asked the question has disappeared five years ago and never been seen since.  So the "tick" will never be removed.

Comment: Even ap person who writes a "ticked" answer cannot remove the "tick"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will not be able to accomplish what you are after using a tapgesture for 1 huge reason.  The tapgesture is associated with the frame of the label.  The labels final frame is changed instantly when kicking off the animation and you are just watching a fake movie(animation).  If you were able to touch (0,900) on the screen it would fire as normal while the animation is occuring.  There is a way to do this a little bit different though.  The best would be to uses touchesBegan.  Here is an extension I just wrote to test my theory but could be adapted to fit your needs.For example you could use your actual subclass and access the label properties without the need for loops.

```
extension UIViewController{

public override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let touch = touches.first else{return}
    let touchLocation = touch.locationInView(self.view)

    for subs in self.view.subviews{
        guard let ourLabel = subs as? UILabel else{return}
        print(ourLabel.layer.presentationLayer())

        if ourLabel.layer.presentationLayer()!.hitTest(touchLocation) != nil{
            print("Touching")
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: {
                self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
                }, completion: {
                    finished in
                    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: {
                        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
                        }, completion: {
                            finished in
                    })
                })
            }
        }

    }
}
```

You can see that it is testing the coordinates of the CALayer.presentationLayer()..That's what I was calling the movies.  To be honest, I have still not wrapped my head completely around the presentation layer and how it works.

Comment: **DON'T DO THIS!** agibson007, you're on the right track, but you simply use the presentation layer!

Answer (score 6):

## How to detect touches in a view which is moving

```
override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {

    let pf = layer.presentation()!.frame
    // note, that is in the space of our superview

    let p = self.convert(point, to: superview!)

    if pf.contains(p) { return self }
    return nil
}
```

## It's that easy

Related tip -

Don't forget that in most cases if an animation is running, you will, of course, almost certainly want to cancel it.  So, say there's a "moving target" and you want to be able to grab it with your finger and slide it somewhere else, naturally in that use case your code in your view controller will look something like ..

```
   func sliderTouched() {
       if alreadyMoving {
          yourPropertyAnimator?.stopAnimation(true)
          yourPropertyAnimator = nil
       }
       etc ...
   }
```

Comment: Can you provide more context on where this code is placed? Do I need to override UIView? Could this be placed in an extension? Do I need to insert any code into the view controller?

Comment: Howdy!  First code sample, Yes, 10000%, you override the view.  In all but the most trivial demos, you override UIView (or whatever view based component).  Enjoy!  Feel free if need to ask more.   Second code sample, as it says "in your view controller..."

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck on this problem for hours, and could not understand why the tapping did not work on an animated label which slides out of screen after 3 seconds delay.

Well said [agibson007](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3641744/agibson007), about the animation works like a fake movie's playback, the 3-second delay controls the payback of the movie, yet the label's frame is changed as soon as the animation begins without a delay. So the tapping (which depends on the label's frame at its original position) would not work.

My solution was changing the 3-second delay to a timeout function like -

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay) {
   [weak self] in
   self?.hideLabel()           
}
```

So that keeps the tapping works during the delay, and allow animation runs inside the hideLabel() call after the delay.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the animation, you need to put it in the `onTap` handler.

```
let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onTap(sender:))
gesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
label.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
label.userInteractionEnabled = true

label.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0)
    
UIView.animateWithDuration(12, delay: 3, options: [.allowUserInteraction], animations: { () -> Void in
      label.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 900)
      }, completion: nil)


func onTap(sender: AnyObject)
{
    print("Tapped")
}
```

Comment: I need the animation to happen *before* the tap. I need to be able to recognize the tap while the view is moving.

Comment: if that is the case just change the delay in your original code to 2 to 3 seconds. I updated my answer.

Comment: It seems like if the animation involves changing the coordinates of the object, gesture can't detect the object.  If your animation is changing just the alpha of the label, the AllowUserInteraction flag will work.

Comment: this is totally unrelated to the problem

Answer (score -1):

For your tap gesture to work, you have to set the number of taps. Add this line:

`tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1`

(I'm assuming that `tapGesture` is the same one you call `label.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)` with)

Comment: What if you take away the ':' in the `onTap:`?

Comment: That would cause the app to crash. `:` tells the tap gesture that it can pass data to `sender`.

Comment: Yeah, something I saw in some of my code that I don think is actually implemented, grasping at straws. One thing - I don't know if I ever saw you call `setUpRecognizers()` - I'd log that to make sure it's set up (and that when you add it, it's set up.

Comment: hm, maybe the superview needs to allow user interactivity?

Comment: This is totally unrelated

Answer (score -1):

Below is a more generic answer based on the answer from @agibson007 in Swift 3.

This didn't solve my issue immediately, because I had additional subviews covering my view. If you have trouble, try changing the extension type and writing print statements for `touchLocation` to find out when the function is firing. The description in the accepted answer explains the issue well.

```
extension UIViewController {

    open override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
        let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self.view)

        for subview in self.view.subviews {

            if subview.tag == VIEW_TAG_HERE && subview.layer.presentation()?.hitTest(touchLocation) != nil {

                print("[UIViewController] View Touched!")
                // Handle Action Here

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: matthew!  you just don't do this in the touches flow (it would be much, much more complex than that anyway).  You just override hitTest !!