# CAKeyframeAnimationGroup position

Tags: ios, swift, animation, caanimation

I have a bunch of animations that added to the CALayer. I need to know the position of the button when it's animating to interact with it. But the frame is not changing.
How can I find/calculate the value? Here is the code:

```
    let positionY = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position.y")
    positionY.values = valuesY
    positionY.keyTimes = keyTimes
    positionY.duration = totalTime
    positionY.isAdditive = true
    positionY.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    // X Position Animation
    let positionX = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position.x")
    positionX.values = valuesX
    positionX.keyTimes = keyTimes
    positionX.duration = 5
    positionX.isAdditive = true
    positionX.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    // Rotation Animation
    let rotation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.z")
    rotation.values = valuesRotation
    rotation.keyTimes = keyTimes
    rotation.duration = totalTime
    rotation.isAdditive = true
    rotation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    // Grouping the animations
    let group = CAAnimationGroup()
    group.animations = [positionX, positionY, rotation]
    group.duration = totalTime
    group.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    group.delegate = self
    group.setValue(button, forKey: GiftGameVC.kAnimationKeyPath)
    group.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    //
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setDisableActions(false)
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
        print("Done")
    }
    button.layer.add(group, forKey: GiftGameVC.kAnimationKeyPath)

    CATransaction.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check the presentationLayer of the button as you are basically watching a movie and the real layer position never changes as you have found.  An example would be something like below.  Also with a layer animation the frame of the view will never change and only the layer position and layers frame. UIView animations can update the frame of the view.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var timer : Timer?
    var animationView = UIView()
    var currentPositionLabel = UILabel()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        animationView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
        animationView.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        animationView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        self.view.addSubview(animationView)

        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y:self.view.bounds.height - 60, width: self.view.bounds.width - 40, height: 40))
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(startAnimation), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        button.setTitle("Restart Animation", for: .normal)
        self.view.addSubview(button)

        currentPositionLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y:button.frame.minY - 50, width: self.view.bounds.width - 40, height: 40))
        currentPositionLabel.textColor = UIColor.gray
        currentPositionLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        currentPositionLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.01
        self.view.addSubview(currentPositionLabel)

        currentPositionLabel.text = "Current Position \(animationView.layer.position)"
    }

    @objc func startAnimation(){

        //prepare to watch a movie/animation while your layer never really moves
        CATransaction.begin()
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
        animation.duration = 20.0
        animation.toValue = NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint(x: self.view.bounds.width - 35, y: self.view.bounds.height - 120))
        CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
            self.timer?.invalidate()
            self.timer = nil
            print("the real position never changed \(self.animationView.layer.position)")
            self.animationView.layer.removeAllAnimations()
            self.currentPositionLabel.text = "Current Position \(self.animationView.layer.position)"
        }
        animationView.layer.add(animation, forKey: "animationViewPosition")
        //if you really want to update the real position of the layer i do it here
        //self.animationView.layer.position = CGPoint(x: self.view.bounds.width - 35, y: self.view.bounds.height - 120)
        //this would mean when the animation is removed that the layer is there but still would not give you the current value
        //of the layer position
        CATransaction.commit()

        if let _ = timer{
            //do nothing we are good to go
        }else{
            //start a new timer
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.01, target: self, selector: #selector(timerUpdateAnimationPosition), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }
    }

    @objc func timerUpdateAnimationPosition(){
        //get presentation layer
        if let presLayer = self.animationView.layer.presentation(){
            if let animationPosition = presLayer.value(forKeyPath: "position") as? CGPoint{
                self.currentPositionLabel.text = "Animation Position : \(animationPosition)"
            }

        }
    }
}
```

You can see in the function timerUpdateAnimationPosition that I checked the presentationLayer for the animation position.  For interaction at the animation position see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35998808/tap-gesture-on-animating-uiview-not-working/36002649#36002649) . But if that is what you are looking for it means the answer above is correct as well.

Comment: Thank you for your help it really helped me

Answer (score 0):

As you've already noticed; the value of an property doesn't change when you add an animation for that key path.  If you want to know the state of the layer as it currently appears onscreen, you can access the layer's [`presentationLayer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410744-presentation):

> The layer object returned by this method provides a close approximation of the layer that is currently being displayed onscreen. While an animation is in progress, you can retrieve this object and use it to get the current values for those animations.

In your case, you would get the buttons animated position using `button.layer.presentationLayer.position`.

---

Related: since you're stopping the animations from being removed after they finish and are using a forward fill mode, you are persisting this difference between the "model layer" and the "presentation layer". In other words; you're making it look like these properties have changed, but in actuality they haven't. This is generally considered a bad practice and can   result in strange and unintended behavior; for example a button now being tappable where it appears on screen but at the same time being tappable at its location before the animation.

To avoid these types of issues it's best to update the property before adding the animation so that it matches the final value of the animation. This way, the difference between "model layer" and "presentation layer" only exists during the animation.

In your code you would remove all the `.isRemovedOnCompletion = false` lines and the `.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards` line, and instead set the `position` and `transform` of the button's layer to their final values before adding the animation group to the layer.